# How to pass multi parameters from controller to resource

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

in my controller

```
 API.logInCheck().get({ nid: $scope.username, pwd: $scope.password, comname: $scope.comtyname }).$promise.then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.popup('success', JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function(err) {
            $rootScope.popup('err', JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

in my service

```
 return $resource(base + '/user/:nid/:pwd/:comname', { nid: 'nid', pwd: 'pwd', comname: 'comname' });
```

in my server

```
router.route('/user/:nid/:pwd/:comname')
.get(function(req, res) {
Community.findOne({ community_name: req.params.comname }, function(err, commu) {
    if (err)
        res.json(err);
    else {

        User.findOne({ username: req.params.nid, password: req.params.pwd, comty_id: commu._id }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.json(err);
                res.json(user);
        });

    }
});
```

but it return an array !
and i want the url to be

```
/user/123/123456/text
```

how ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @ in $ressouce :

```
return $resource(base + '/user/:nid/:pwd/:comname', { nid: '@nid', pwd: '@pwd', comname: '@comname' });
```

Your call :

```
API.logInCheck().query({ nid: $scope.username, pwd: $scope.password, comname: $scope.comtyname }).$promise.then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.popup('success', JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function(err) {
            $rootScope.popup('err', JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

Comment: in this way the url looks like this "/user?nid=123&&pwd=123456&&comname=text"

Comment: Should work now with query. if you want to use get, you will have to rewrite it in your $ressource.

Comment: i don't want to pass the parameters as query string but as req.params